# Material-UI DateTimePicker doesn't work if I have two in the same form

Tags: reactjs

I have a single form where all the other input fields(strings) are set correctly. However the two date pickers don't seem to set the correct value when they are submitted.

```
    <div className='form-control'>
        <label htmlFor='dateFrom'>Date from:</label>
        <DateTimePicker value={selectedDateFrom} onChange={handleDateFromChange}/>
    </div>

    <div className='form-control'>
        <label htmlFor='dateTo'>Date to:</label>
        <DateTimePicker value={selectedDateTo} onChange={handleDateToChange}/>
    </div>
```

and I also have this:

```
    const [selectedDateFrom, setSelectedDateFrom] = useState(new Date());
    const [selectedDateTo, setSelectedDateTo] = useState(new Date());

    const handleDateFromChange = (date) => {
        console.log("handle date from change ", date);
        setSelectedDateFrom(date)
    }

    const handleDateToChange = (date) => {
        console.log("handle date to change ", date);
        setSelectedDateTo(date)
    }
```

when I run the program only one console log is printed and I can't see why

Comment: I ran the code, but change the date picker to input tag and it seems to work fine, so my thought is that there is something to do with the datepicker component itself...

Comment: @DobromirKirov what do you mean change the date picker input tag? Sorry that bit wasnt clear

Comment: Instead of the datepicker component i put just an input tag, like so: <input value={selectedDateFrom} onChange={handleDateFromChange} />

Comment: I did some digging @DobromirKirov and it turns out the issues is in transforming the date to another format and not with the date picker - sorry for that:
moment("January 10th 10:22 pm",  "MMMM DDDo hhmm A").format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')
it transforms my date to 2022-01-01T22:22:00 which is not the same as the one i passed in? Do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be disregarded as it was something to do with moment parsing that was the real issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).